# Flash lags after getting back from suspend

Tags: flash

I have a problem I on my device HP dv4 with i3 processor

After getting back from suspend the flash player on youtube or any other website lags on full screen ... audio goes perfect but video is lagging I tried some solutions from google nothing worked ... So am seeking the experts help here

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the suspend feature.  I'm going to assume by "Suspend" you mean "Hibernate".  This kind of issue is well known to be caused by the hibernation feature in Linux.  My advice is to restart your computer, and try to not hibernate your computer (if you can avoid it).